# dash drawing different graph when clicking on different button

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to draw graph A when clicking on button A and graph B when clicking on button B, if either graphs is drawn and I click on either button I want the page to be updated with the new graph, I'm using dash and plotly, here the pseudo code

```
@app.callback([Output("graph-content", "children")],[Input("KPI_gauge","n_clicks")])
def kpi_gauge(v): 
  if v == None:
    raise PreventUpdate
  fig1 = KPIGauge(88.7,102)
  return [dcc.Graph(figure=fig1)]

@app.callback([Output("graph-content", "children")],[Input("comparaison_graph","n_clicks")]
def comparaison_graph(v):
  if v == None:
    raise PreventUpdate
  fig = ComparaisonGraph()
  return [dcc.Graph(figure=fig)]
```

but I get this error dash duplicate callback output, how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

- https://dash.plotly.com/callback-gotchas  A component/property pair can only be the Output of one callback.  Your code broke this rule, **graph-content** was the output of two callbacks
- this code demonstrates a way to output **plotly** figure on first click and update data in graph on subsequent clicks

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import dash
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import random
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button("KPI", id="KPI_gauge", n_clicks=0),
        html.Button("Graph", id="comparaison_graph", n_clicks=0),
        html.Div(id="graph-content"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("graph-content", "children"),
    Input("KPI_gauge", "n_clicks"),
    Input("comparaison_graph", "n_clicks"),
    State("graph-content", "children"),
)
def update_graph(kpi_but, graph_but, content):
    if not kpi_but and not graph_but:
        raise PreventUpdate
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    button = ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]
    fig_id = f"{button}_fig"
        
    if button=="KPI_gauge":
        if content and content["type"]=="Graph" and content["props"]["id"]==fig_id: # update
            fig = content["props"]["figure"]
            fig["data"][0]["value"] = random.randint(0,400)
        else: # create
            fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(mode="gauge+number",value=270,title={"text": "KPI"},))
    elif button=="comparaison_graph":
        if content and content["type"]=="Graph" and content["props"]["id"]==fig_id: # update
            fig = content["props"]["figure"]
            fig["data"][0]["y"] = np.sort(np.random.uniform(1,5,365*2))
        else: # create

            df = pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range("1-aug-2019", periods=365*2), "value":np.linspace(1,5,365*2)})
            fig = px.line(df, x="date", y="value")
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
    return dcc.Graph(id=fig_id, figure=fig)

app.run_server(mode="inline", port=8051)
```